# Running Kotlin REPL with JVM Target 1.8?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

How can I configure the "Kotlin Repl" to use JVM target 1.8 and not 1.6 in Intellij? When trying to create a `Stream`  in the repl it shows me this error message:

```
"/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java" -Dkotlin.repl.ideMode=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @/private/var/folders/9z/tqq6c03j3l33pv9k1c24hsnw0000gn/T/idea_arg_file175649686
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.4.0 (JRE 11.0.8+10-b944.31)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit

java.util.stream.Stream.of("test")
error: calls to static methods in Java interfaces are prohibited in JVM target 1.6. Recompile with '-jvm-target 1.8'
java.util.stream.Stream.of("test")
```

I have tried to configuring the Kotlin compiler to use 1.8 and restarting the REPL but it doesn't help:
[image]

I'm using intellij 2020.2.1. How can I fix this?

Comment: For me my setting is 1.6 as well, but when I open `Kotlin REPL` under tools, it is using 14.

Comment: Go to project structure -> project -> project language level. Check if that is also set to 1.8 as well as the project SDK.

Comment: @Daniel yes the language level is set to 8

Comment: I believe this should be fixed in Kotlin 1.4: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38454. Please make sure that the context IDE module has a jvm target set properly (in build.gradle or in a Kotlin facet in project structure dialog). For example, in gradle scripts the default jvm target is 1.6.